# References to learn modern functions applied to integration and numerical series problems and how to teach them to Calculus students

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, reference-request, education

I think most of us have met integration problems concerning the trigonometric, polynomial, exponential, hyperbolic and power functions in the calculus courses. But many of the problems in this website which deal with numerical series as well as integration are far beyond the common curricula required in most mathematics undergraduate programs. For example, most of the times we are interested in the convergence of numerical sequences, but we often do not discuss the value of its convergence. Similarly, there many functions which are not standard, but which are frequently used to solve harder integrals.

Having said that, my question is: is there any suggestion about how we can master such advanced techniques for our own development as well as for the sake of students' knowledge enhancement?

I would be thankful for any reference on the subject.

Comment: "we often do not discuss the value of its convergence".  Well, a typical infinite series has no simple expression for its value. It just is what it is, so the most realistic thing we can do is just ask how to estimate the value rather than to compute it in some tidy formula.

Comment: What do you mean by "for the sake of students' knowledge enhancement"?  I would not spend time talking about the Gamma function, zeta function, or other well known advanced transcendental functions in a calculus course.  If you start lecturing a lot on math way beyond the scope of the syllabus, students will tune you out because they'll realize you're not covering anything relevant to the course.  (I am not referring here to a 5-second comment about some unexpected integral or series with a closed formula involving $\pi$ that can only be proved by, say, complex analysis).

Comment: @KCd Thanks for the comment. I agree with the first answer. But I am talking about results such as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}} = \frac{\pi^{2}}{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: What about that?  I mention this example when I teach infinite series (and point out no analogous formula is known for $\sum 1/n^3$, especially that it's not expected to be related in any simple way to $\pi^3$). It takes a minute and I move on. Do you think something more should be done?  If the students are learning Fourier series then there are several ways to derive the formula for $\sum 1/n^2$, but Fourier series is not a standard topic in a calculus course.

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [References to learn modern functions applied to integration and numerical series problems and how to teach them to Calculus students](https://mathoverflow.net/q/423651).

Comment: Now posted on [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/): [References to learn modern functions applied to integration and numerical series problems and how to teach them to Calculus students](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/25294/745), where I first saw it a few minutes ago and suggested in comments that my experience has been that one typically learns about this stuff in undergraduate and graduate level "mathematical methods" courses for physicists and engineers (which pure math students likely miss out on unless taking a broad range of math electives).